# SARIMA is running out of memory in Python statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a SARIMA model on a time series. The interval between data points is 15 minutes and in total, I have a 1-D array of **shape (29204,)**

There is a seasonality and pattern repeats every 56 timesteps.

The code and error is shown below:

```
model = SARIMAX(train_office,order=(1,1,2),seasonal_order=(1, 0, 2, 56))
model.fit()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File statsmodels\tsa\statespace\_kalman_smoother.pyx:1015, in statsmodels.tsa.statespace._kalman_smoother.dKalmanSmoother.allocate_arrays()

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.93 GiB for an array with shape (116, 116, 29205) and data type float64
```

Is there a more efficient way to use the model or is there a mistake in the code?

Comment: Maybe `model.fit(low_memory=True)` [could help](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6034#issuecomment-518054251)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. I tried just after posting this. It seemed to work. Do you know how it affects the results?